# How to open socket over wifi given an SSID

Tags: android, sockets, wifimanager

I want to open a connection over Wi-Fi. My current code is:

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", "MY_SSID");
wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", "MY_PASSWORD");

int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
if (netId != -1 ) {
     wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
}
```

`enableNetwork` returns true which means the operation is successful. I'm not sure what to do next though.

My goal is to open a socket where I can do custom I/O over the network I have just connected to. How can I open a socket with this network? Also, how can I make sure that I actually connected to the network (is there a `BroadcastReceiver` I can setup)?

Any links or documentation would be awesome, I'm not sure what to search online

Comment: `I want to open a connection over Wi-Fi.`. To what? Which two 'things' do you want to connect?

Comment: To the network I have added. My android phone and the network displayed in the code

Comment: To connect your phone to a wireless network you don:t need sockets. What is wrong with your code? If the phone is connected to the wireless router... Then what. I find this all so vague. Please explain better your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must run a server on first device with any port you like, I'm trying 9000 in this example:

```
try {
    log("Waiting for client...");

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);
    socket = serverSocket.accept();

    log("A new client Connected!");
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

then search for this server on the other device on port 9000. in this example would be:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {
    String ip = range + i;
    try {
        log("Try IP: " + ip);
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 9000), 10);

        log("Connected!");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

if you have the server ip you don't need loop.
and for a simple chat you we must open an inputstream and outputstream like this:

```
try {
    outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    log("Error: Connection is not stable, exit");
    shutdown();
}

while (true) {
    try {
        String message = inputStream.readLine();
        if (message != null) {
            log(message);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

and send message with:

```
try {
    String message = input.getText().toString() + "\n";
    outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

for file I/O use the same way.

Comment: can you please explain how you are getting IP of server device in `String ip = range + i`?? I need IP to connect to server device but i don't know how to get IP of that device. If i'm using `host name` instead of IP then exception is raised `Host is unresolved: de:e8:38:16:d4:fb`

Comment: do you want get IP in localhost? or on the internet?

Comment: .thanks for reply...i got ip in method wifip2pmanager.requestConnectionInfo()